# Unable to retrieve an image from a video

Tags: android, media

I am using `getFrameAtTime()` method of `MediaMetadataRetriever` class to get a frame located at a particular time in a video(mp4). This works fine when the video is of low resolution say 480 x 270. But if I use HD version (1280 x 720) of same video then it gives error. Is there any way out ?

Logcat:

06-11 08:24:45.714: D/dalvikvm(511): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 41K, 53% free 2550K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 120ms

06-11 08:24:46.974: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(511): getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer

Code is this:

```
package com.asin.amit;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;

import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AsinActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private MediaMetadataRetriever mediam;
private Bitmap bmp;
private int g;

private ImageView myImageView;
private TextView tv ;

@Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mediam = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        String str= "/sdcard/DCIM/wdc.mp4";
        mediam.setDataSource(str);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle any errors
        Log.e("HelloWorld", "1", e);  // log the error
        // Also let the user know something went wrong
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        bmp=mediam.getFrameAtTime();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle any errors
        Log.e("HelloWorld", "2", e);  // log the error
        // Also let the user know something went wrong
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I was using videos downloaded from internet. But if you use videos shot by mobile it will work.